# IN, BETWEEN - timestamp or timestamptz data types

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE column_date IN ('2021-01-01','2021-06-01')
```

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE column_date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-03-01'
```

If we are dealing with IN and BETWEEN, we can use the below-mentioned queries - but only if the data type is 'date'. But if it's timestamp or timestamptz - these queries don't work.
How do I have to write queries with IN (some certain dates) and BETWEEN (period) if the date type is timestamp or timestamptz?

Comment: "...But if it's timestamp or timestamptz - these queries don't work..." -- Yes, they do.

Comment: Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result that demonstrates the case.

Comment: Neither in nor between is suitable for datetime range queries. Instead simply use datetime range queries like: myCol >= dtStart and myVCol < dtEnd (or a query using postgreSQL range type)

Comment: @CetinBasoz `IN` works well for specific TIMESTAMP values, and `BETWEEN` works well for TIMESTAMP [inclusive] ranges.

Comment: @TheImpaler, with a timestamp value using BETWEEN is asking for trouble. How do you think you would specify the ending value? And for the in it is even more problematic, how do you think you would obtain the exact comparison values to use in IN? If you could suceed that then of cource it would work.

Comment: Actually, the data marked as 'timestamp with time zone' looks like -  2022-04-25 10:56:15+03. That's why I decided that we can't use IN and BETWEEN for timestamp or timestamptz  as well as for date-type.

Comment: IMHO it is not practical to use BETWEEN with timestamp. For example, can you imagine the values to use that specify a time frame that covers all the values on May 1st, 2022?

Comment: I have already said, simply use >= and <.